# How this formula for numerical integration is derived?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am looking for a derivation of this formula for numerical integration:

$$\int_0^1{f(x)dx}=2\sum_{m=1}^M{\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{{1}}{{{{\left({2M}\right)}^{2n+1}}\left({2n+1}\right)!}}{{\left.{{f^{(2n)}}(x)}\right|}_{x=\frac{{m-1/2}}{M}}}}}\,\,,$$

where $f(x)^{(2n)}$ is 2n-th derivative. It is rapid in convergence and any symbolic software like Maple, Mathematica and Matlab can be used for determination of 2n-th derivatives. Sample computations show that it is efficient for computation of highly oscillating functions $f(x)$. Please let me know how to derive this equation.

Comment: Where did you find this equation? Was it attributed to anyone?

Comment: It looks an avatar of Euler-MacLaurin formula, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Paul. My friend told me that this is the Euler's formula that was discovered year ago in his unpublished notes in archives of the Russian Academy of Sciences. It looks like a joke I guess. But seriously, I do not know where does it come from. I am also curious about its origin and derivation.

Answer (score 0):

By subdivision and scaling you can reduce this to the case $M=1$. Then the formula is just the term-wise integration of the Taylor expansion in $x=\frac12$.

Comment: Is it Euler's formula? If yes, could you please provide a reference?

Comment: I do not know if it is a formula of Euler's, but in the end it is just $\int_0^1 (x-\frac12)^ndx=0$ for $n$ odd and $=\frac1{(n+1)2^n}$ for $n$ even. There is nothing surprising or complicated contained in it, apart from the issue of the limit-swap in the term-wise integration of a power series.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understood the general concept of derivation. Newton - Curtis or Gauss quadrature integration formulas (or any other integration formulas) are also pretty much simple in derivations. However, if this particular formula is simple in derivation and very accurate in approximation, why it is not known? The fact that the professional mathematicians are not familiar with this equation surprises me. But anyway, thank you again for clarification!

Comment: In what sense is it accurate? Evaluating higher order derivatives is never easy, that's why one avoids it in practical quadrature methods, or only uses the first derivative. Taylor integration methods exist, but more as an academic exercise.

Comment: I agree that higher order derivatives are not easy. But who would do it by hand? Any symbolic software can do this boring routine task for us. With same number of terms it is more accurate than the conventional Newton -- Curtis or Gauss quadrature especially for highly oscillating functions. This is not my personal preference but objective results from computer.

Comment: Were the hints enough for the derivation or should I add some formulas?

Comment: I think it is clear. Thank you!