# How this integral is derived?

Tags: integration

There is an interesting definite integral
$$\int_0^1{x^m(1 - x)^n} dx = \frac{n!m!}{(m + n + 1)!}.$$
How to derive this integral?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: see the solution using a recurrence formula by jmerry [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h145241p822220).

Comment: @Masacroso: It is a complicated derivation. Is there an elementary derivation?

Comment: @Jean Marie: Thank you! This looks clear.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad: I have tried if this equation can be derived by using integration formula shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$I(m,n) = \int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n \, dx.$$
It's straightforward to prove that $I(n,0)=I(0,n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$, which satisfies the given formula.

Now note that
$$x^m(1-x)^n = x^m(1-x)^{n-1}(1-x) = x^m(1-x)^{n-1} - x^{m+1}(1-x)^{n-1}.$$
So
$$I(m,n) = I(m,n-1) - I(m+1, n-1),$$
which gives
$$I(m+1,n-1) = I(m, n-1) - I(m,n).$$
Now we induct on $m$; if it is true for some $m$, and all $n$, then we have
\begin{align*}
I(m+1, n-1) &= \frac{m!(n-1)!}{(m+n)!} - \frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}\\
&= \frac{m!(n-1)!}{(m+n+1)!}\left(m+n+1-n\right)\\
&= \frac{m!(n-1)!}{(m+n+1)!} \cdot (m+1)\\
&= \frac{(m+1)!(n-1)!}{(m+n+1)!}.
\end{align*}
So the statement is now true for $m+1$ and all $n$, and we are done.